# Passar model da JSP para controller SpringMVC

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc, página-de-erro

Alguém poderia por favor me explicar como corrigir o erro da minha JSP?

Este formulário irá servir para cadastrar produtos em meu sistema, ele recebe uma lista de categorias de produtos vinda do banco de dados.

Meu Controller ProdutoController.java:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import br.com.estoque.Dao.CategoriaProdutoDao;
import br.com.estoque.Dao.ProdutoDao;
import br.com.estoque.Modelo.Produto;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("controllerProduto")
public class ProdutoController {

    @RequestMapping("produtoForm")
    public String loginForm(Model model){
        CategoriaProdutoDao dao = new CategoriaProdutoDao();
        model.addAttribute("lista", dao.listar());
        return "produtos/frmCadastroProduto";
    }

    /*@RequestMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView home(ModelMap model){
        model.put("lista",dao.listar());
        System.out.println("categoria achada");
        return new ModelAndView("categoriaProduto",model);
    }*/

    @RequestMapping(value = "/inserirProduto", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody()
    public String inserirProduto(@ModelAttribute("inserirProdutoForm")Produto produto, ModelMap model){
        ProdutoDao dao = new ProdutoDao();
        model.addAttribute("categoriaProduto", produto.getCategoriaProduto().getCdCategoriaProduto());
        model.addAttribute("descricao", produto.getDescricao());

        dao.adiciona(produto);
        return "produtoForm";
    }
}
```

Minha JSP:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>   
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Registration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div align="center">
    <form:form action="/inserirProduto" method="post">

        <table border="0">   

        <tr>
    <td><form:label path="descricao">Nome Produto</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="descricao" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="categoriaProduto">id</form:label></td>
    <td><form:select path="categoriaProduto" items="${lista}"  /></td>
</tr>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </form:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

E o erro que está me retornando:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/produtos/frmCadastroProduto.jsp at line 18

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/produtos/frmCadastroProduto.jsp at line 18

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/produtos/frmCadastroProduto.jsp at line 18

15:             <table border="0">   
16:             
17:             <tr>
18:         <td><form:label path="descricao">Nome Produto</form:label></td> 
19:         <td><form:input path="descricao" /></td>
20:     </tr>
21:     <tr>
```

Comment: Acredito que `${lista}` contenha uma lista de alguma classe sua. Não tenho certeza, mas nesse caso você não precisa setar os atributos `itemValue="id"` `itemLabel="nome"` do `form:select`? Segundo [a documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-optionstag), deveria funcionar, mas não custa tentar :)

Comment: Já fiz as devidas modificações no meu form:select , obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Conforme a [documentação das taglibs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html), o atributo `path` das tags `<form:*>` devem receber um atributo de um Java Bean para que seja feito o *binding*, isto é, os métodos *getter* e *setter* serão invocados para, respectivamente, recuperar e definir o valor do *bean* de acordo com o valor do campo.

Em outras palavras: **não** dá para fazer *binding* em um campo de formuário direto com ums `String`, precisa ser com um atributo de um objeto.

**Solução**: crie um Java Bean contendo atributos para os campos do formulário para servir como *model*.

Answer (score 2):

amigo, de uma olhada nesses [exemplos](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view-jsp-formtaglib-formtag).

Você precisa especificar um objeto `command` no seu model lá no seu controlador.

`model.addAttribute("command", new MyObject());`

Lembrando que esse objeto `command` precisa ter um método `getter` e `setter` para o atributo que você especifica no `path` do `input`.

Um exemplo bem simples:

Objeto:

```
public class Pessoa {

  private String nome;

  public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
  }

  public String getNome() {
    return nome;
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/pessoa")
public class ProdutoController {

  @RequestMapping("/form")
  public String form(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("command", new Pessoa());
    return "pessoa/form";
  }
}
```

form.jsp:

```
<form:form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nome:</td>
            <td><form:input path="nome"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```